# codeigniter ion_auth admin groups

Tags: codeigniter

Hi
is it possible to have more than one group as admin_group? being able to change users?
or, in alternative, how can i add one user to more than one group?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "admin" group is just another named group.  There is nothing special about it other than it has a shortcut to check that role with...

```
$this->ion_auth->is_admin();
```

instead of just using...

```
$this->ion_auth->is_group('admin_group');
```

so really it all depends on how **YOU** treat the users.

so, to allow 2 groups admin access I'd just do this... Note `is_group()` can accept an array of strings also.

```
$admin_groups = array('admin_group1','admin_group2');

if ($this->ion_auth->is_group($admin_groups)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: nice, but i had the impression that only a member of an admin group could change users data. Am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, there are no actual permissions associated with the user groups, you as the developer are to set that up.

Comment: The latest version of Ion Auth allows a user to belong to multiple groups.